# Add constant size to border-style:dotted(CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` that has with  `border-style:dotted` and I want to add a fixed size for this element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YCHE4/288/), if I add text to this span the size automatically increases. Is there a CSS property to add a fixed size i.e. create an empty dotted element?

Code without fixed size:

```
<span style="border-width: 1px; border-style: dotted; font-size: 11pt">
    <font face="David" class="ng-binding">
        &nbsp;
    </font>
</span>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YCHE4/289/  Add display:block and desired width...

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for,

Comment: Look up the difference between block and inline elements. This is crucial in understanding CSS.

Comment: You can simply add `max-width:40px;min-width:40px` to the style, which will make it fixed regardless of any change (of screen side or contained text).

Comment: Thanks, that works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `display: block;` CSS property with a `width`.

Try this:

```
<span style="display:block; width: 100px; border-width: 1px; border-style: dotted; font-size: 11pt">
    <font face="David" class="ng-binding">
        &nbsp;
    </font>
</span>
```

Where the `width` value can be whatever desired width you want. I just used `100px` as an example.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `display:inline-block` and a `width:` propertie. And the size of the element don't depend on the border. Like [so](http://jsfiddle.net/YCHE4/290/).